# Using the "super" keyword in a class method decleration

Tags: java

Why is "this super" not allowed in a Java class method definition? For example,

```
class Dog{
  public <T super Dog> void display(ArrayList<T> t){
     t.add()
  }
}
```

Comment: [that might be wort a read](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4343547/1799530)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between <? super T> and <? extends T> in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because super of a class is always Object class so it means it act as
public **<Object>** void display(ArrayList **<Object>** t)
{}

And it allow every class object to pass in display function parameter which is not good for genrics.So that's why super is not allow in function definition there.